# Why my markers move when I resize my map on Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have already get an eye on Google and seen that the solution should be the iconAnchor property.

I have set it to the same values that my iconSize. But it fails. When I resize my map the icon change their location with the map resizing.

How can I ensure my marker remain responsively on the same location?

Here my marker' code:

```
var placeholder1 = L.icon({
      iconUrl: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/484/484167.svg",
      iconSize:     [47, 47], // size of the icon
      iconAnchor:   [47, 47], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
      popupAnchor:  [-25, -50], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
      tooltipAnchor:[30, -2]
    });

    var placeholder2 = L.icon({
      iconUrl: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/484/484167.svg", 
      iconSize:     [47, 47], // size of the icon 
      iconAnchor:   [47, 47], 
      popupAnchor:  [-25, -50], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
      tooltipAnchor:[10, -2]
    });

    var placeholder3 = L.icon({
      iconUrl: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/484/484167.svg", 
      iconSize:     [47, 47], // size of the icon 
      iconAnchor:   [47, 47], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location 
      popupAnchor:  [-25, -50], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
      tooltipAnchor:[0, 0]
    });

    var placeholder4 = L.icon({
      iconUrl: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/484/484167.svg", 
      iconSize:     [47, 47], // size of the icon 
      iconAnchor:   [47, 47], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location 
      popupAnchor:  [-25, -50], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
      tooltipAnchor:[-30, 130]
    });


var marker1 = L.marker(location ,{icon: placeholder1}).addTo(this.map); 
var marker2 = L.marker(location ,{icon: placeholder2}).addTo(this.map); 
var marker3 = L.marker(location ,{icon: placeholder3}).addTo(this.map); 
var marker4 = L.marker(location ,{icon: placeholder4}).addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: The lower-right corner of the icons stays in place, as expected. Please read https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#icon-iconanchor carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the icon you use, you should change `iconAnchor` value into `[23.5, 47]`.

```
var placeholder = L.icon({
    iconUrl: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/484/484167.svg",
    iconSize:     [47, 47],
    iconAnchor:   [23.5, 47], // CHANGE HERE
    popupAnchor:  [-25, -50],
    tooltipAnchor:[30, -2]
});
```

[image]

---

Values change depending on anchor point location in any icon and depending on `iconSize` you defined for it. For an icon like in the image, `iconAnchor` values should be like that:

```
iconSize  iconAnchor
   x         x/2
   y          y
```